# boot: why wait for a removable SCSI disk?

Tags: boot, lvm, scsi

I have turned off quiet and splash to see why my boot takes so long on my new SSD.

I see the following at 3.xx seconds:

```
sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

then it sits there for 30 seconds and at 33.xx seconds:

```
Begin: Waiting for suspend/resume device ... Begin: Running /scripts/...
random: fast init done
```

I have only one disk (and this is only removable with a screw driver), I imagine it could be waiting for a card in the SD card reader?

Here is the extract from dmesg:

```
[    3.172236] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    3.177895] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   33.999093] random: fast init done
```

And I noticed more in my screenshot (not in the dmesg output):
[image: photo from boot screen]

Answer (score 0):

The warning in the screenshot appears to be the culprit:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
```

This is a known problem, as described in this bug for 18.04:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1768230